# How can I install another version of my app on the same device? [no gradle]

Tags: android, build, apk, android-manifest

I'm building an app from github source, and I need two different versions of it on the same device.
What's the minimum an app must differ, to be a different app?
I'd like a small change, and not rename packages everywhere.

NB: No gradle. I'm doing it on the device itself (using termux), which lacks gradle.
The app itself has some native code, and a few different packages.

It seems the *package* name in the *AndroidManifest.xml* must differ, and of course any classes referenced explicitly referenced in the *AndroidManifest.xml* must also exist.

But is that enough? Specifically, can the following be the same:

- everything else in *AndroidManifest.xml*?
- all other classes in the main package?
- other packages in the app?
- native libraries?

I'm guessing that all the other names in the manifest are just decoration, and don't identify the app. So that e.g. different apps could have the same name on the homescreen.

The package name is used to name the directory the app is installed in, so all its other data - dex classes, native libraries etc - are distinct.

It would be sensible for android to load each app with a different classloader, so different apps can have the same packages. This avoids clashes in the common scenario of  different apps using the same (popular) library, that uses static/class fields.

My guesses are derived from this answer:
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20793/108921

If so... I could just make one new package, move the classes referenced into it, and use this new package name in the *AndroidManifest.xml*. (There might be issues with these classes accessing other classes which were formerly in the same one package, but I suppose that's a different issue).

Answer (score 0):

its hard to believe... package name is like ID i think... google play store also use package name as ID... every app has to unique ID in every device, and finally i can say its impossible you can install 2 app have same package name in 1 device

Comment: My question suggests using a different package name.

Comment: If you have a look at the rest of the question, I suggest keeping the same packages *except* for the one referenced from the manifest (see the last paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml (*manifest package*).  This can differ from the java packages of your codebase.

There's some caveats. The `aapt` tool uses the manifest package to generate `R.java`. Any relative names (of Activities etc) in the AndroidManifest.xml are completed into absolute names using the manifest package. To avoid this, just use absolute names.

As a convenience, the `--rename-manifest-package` option of the `aapt` tool does that. i.e. completes any relative names, then changes the manifest package to the argument given.

I've tested this with a simple project, and confirmed it works to install different versions of the same app on the same device.

> I haven't tested more complex projects... There may be further caveats, with aspects of the AndroidManifest.xml that constitute a public API, and Activities, Services, ContentProviders and BroadcastReceivers that are referenced with **explicit** Intents. [Things That Cannot Change
>   20 June 2011](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html?m=1)

The docs confirm you can change your java packages from the original; and that you can create different versions (flavors) of the same app. Unfortunately, it's discussed in terms of an extra layer of how gradle reads and updates the AndroidManifest.xml, not doing it yourself directly:
[Set the application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#modify_the_package_name)